# Change icon in sharepoint site programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I want to change the icon image for my Webapplication , not the logo but the icon in the URl .
I used this script powerShell to change the logo :

```
#Get the Site
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://mig-sp-88:1060/"

#Set Site Logo Icon
$web.SiteLogoUrl = "http://mig-sp-88:1060/SiteAssets/NewIdea.jpg"

#Set Logo Description
$web.SiteLogoDescription = "Corporate Logo for Your Company"

#Update the changes
$web.Update()
```

But how to do to change the icon in URL .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon in the URL is defined as 'favicon.ico' and is not hosted within SharePoint, but rather on the File System on your servers.

You can change this manually by navigating to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IMAGES and replacing the favicon.ico file.

Surprisingly, you can also change this in the Master page for the site.  It can be found by looking for the following:

```
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon ID="SPShortcutIcon1" runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/images/favicon.ico"/>
```

By adding a file (with a name of your choosing) somewhere on the site, you can modify this line to point to the new icon file through the master page.

As far as programatically doing it, you would need to modify the master page programatically which I would advise against - there is so much potential for errors that it could bring your entire site collection down.    Alternatively, you could code a feature for deployment that modifies the file directly on the file system.  Also ill-advised to do programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to change the favicon using jslink/javascript.
Something lite this:

```
var fi = document.querySelector('link[rel="shortcut icon"]');
fi.setAttribute('type', 'image/png');
fi.setAttribute('href', '/SiteAssets/favicon.png');
```